# Pig Latin in Rust

Tags: rust, pig-latin

I feel like this code can be written in a better way but don't know how. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
mod string_man {
    pub fn first_ch(txt: &String) -> char {
        txt.chars().next().unwrap()
    }

    pub fn pigify(txt: &String) -> String {
        let frstch = first_ch(txt);

        match frstch {
            'a' |
            'e' |
            'i' |
            'o' |
            'u' => {
                txt[..].to_string() + "-hay"
            },
            _   => {
                txt[1..].to_string() + "-" + &frstch.to_string() + "ay"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be cool to write what you actually trying to do. The code doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score -2):

````rust
mod string_man {
    // This is needed to handle caller passing you multiple words.
    // Although it still won't handle punctuation correctly.
    // "Hello world" works, for example, but "Hello world." doesn't.
    // I ran out of steam to solve this problem; so I leave it as
    // an exercise :). There are many things a caller could pass
    // here that probably won't do what you want
    pub fn pigify<S>(s: S) -> String where S: AsRef<str> {
        let mut output = String::new();
        let mut first = true;
        for word in s.as_ref().split_whitespace() {
            let s = pigify_word_simple(word);
            if first {
                output += &s;
                first = false;
                continue;
            }
            output += " ";
            output += &s;
        }
        output
    }

    // Simple version of pigifying a word that I would probably do in practice...
    fn pigify_word_simple<S>(s: S) -> String
    where
        S: AsRef<str>,
    {
        let s = s.as_ref();

        let beginning = match s.chars().next() {
            Some(c) => c.to_lowercase().to_string(),
            None => return "".to_string(),
        };

        match beginning.as_ref() {
            "a" | "e" | "i" | "o" | "u" => s.to_string() + "-hay",
            _ => (&s[1..]).to_string() + "-" + &beginning + "ay",
        }
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    // Overly complicated version of pigifying a word that is probably a tiny, tiny bit faster...
    fn pigify_word_complex<S>(s: S) -> String
    where
        S: AsRef<str>,
    {
        // Using this trait give you the `write_str` and `write_char` methods on
        // `String`, which are used below (see pigify).
        use std::fmt::Write;

        // After this line, s will be a `&str`.
        let s = s.as_ref();

        let beginning = match s.chars().next() {
            // Would use `to_lowercase` here, which returns an iterator of chars because
            // I guess the lowercase equivalent of some utf-8 characters are actually
            // sets of more than one character. So we also call to_string() on the iterator
            // to turn it into a String.
            Some(c) => c.to_lowercase().to_string(),
            // Return an empty string if someone provides an empty S as input.
            None => return "".to_string(),
        };

        // You know the maximum possible size of the String you will be returning; so
        // when you allocate it, tell Rust to reserve enough capacity so it
        // won't have to do any reallocations as it writes data into it.
        let mut output = String::with_capacity(s.len() + beginning.len() + 3);

        match beginning.as_ref() {
            // This will now match any vowel (uppercase or lowercase) because of the
            // call to `to_lowercase()` above, which is I think what you want.
            "a" | "e" | "i" | "o" | "u" => {
                output.write_str(s).unwrap();
                output.write_str("-hay").unwrap();
            }
            _ => {
                // Indexing into a `&str` like this is safe, but only because
                // we know from the early return above that s is not empty.
                // In general, though, be careful with indexing into a &str
                // (or into any slice in general).
                output.write_str(&s[1..]).unwrap();
                output.write_str("-").unwrap();
                output.write_str(&beginning).unwrap();
                output.write_str("ay").unwrap();
            }
        }

        // Final note: I don't think any of the unwraps above can ever fail,
        // but someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

        output
    }
}
```
````